# mongoose document to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to return a set of mongoose documents as plain old JavaScript objects. I have a `user.js` module that handles the querying of the database -

```
module.exports = function() {
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log('connection successful');
});
var outingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id : String,
    location : String,
    date : Date,
    participantCount : Number,
    confirmedParticipantCount : Number,
    group : String
});
var Outing = mongoose.model('Outing', outingSchema);

this.dashboard = function() {
    var result = Outing.find({}, function(err, outings) {
        console.log('##################');
    });
    db.close();
    return result;
}
}
```

And this is my main `server.js` file -

```
io.of('/user').on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log('Incoming connection to ' + socket.namespace.name);
var User = require('./real/user.js');
var UserObject = new User();
socket.on('dashboard', function(data) {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(UserObject.dashboard(), null, 3));
})
});
```

As it stands, this always results in an exception -

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

I'm assuming this is happening because the mongoose Document object has some sort of circular structure. How can I have the `dashboard()` method just return regular JavaScript objects that I can convert to JSON using `JSON.stringify()`?

I've tried looping over `outings' and calling the`toObject()` method on each document, but that just returns the mongoose Document object as well.

What's also weird is that the statement `console.log('##################');` is never executed as far as I can tell (I don't see the output in the console). Is this because it is in a callback function? Other `console.log()` statements in other callback functions work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need your 'dashboard' function to be a callback.

```
this.dashboard = function(callback) {
    Outing.find({}, callback);
};
```

You'll rarely want to actually close the db between requests with node.

```
socket.on('dashboard', function(data) {
    UserObject.dashboard(function(err, results){
      if(err){
        //send the error to the socket
      }
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(results);
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I don't really understand what I was doing wrong in the first place though. Why does `dashboard` have to be a callback? Also, the JSON string includes `_id` and `__v` properties. Is there any way I can exclude those from the representation?

Comment: You can forget the second part of the followup question. I used `query.select('- excludedField')` to perform a projection. Could you just explain why I had to transform `dashboard` into a callback?

Comment: Because nodejs is non-blocking, you don't get the results of the query right away. They aren't returned from the statement like some languages. The callback function is executed when the results are ready. Read up on nodejs and callbacks. http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/nodejs-for-beginners-callbacks/4